# Flutter Dependency and Kernel format version error

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors, sdk, dependencies, kernel

I'm facing dependency and kernel format version errors. Can someone please assist me in fixing these issues?

Dependency Error
[image]

Kernel Error
[image]

While resolving Dependency error, I have downgraded the Flutter SDK and from that point I am facing Kernel format version error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When I add "google_mobile_ads" and "google_ml_kit" plugins to my project, it throws a Dependency error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here **images** which represent textual information are discouraged. Please, [edit] your question post and copy paste the errors into it as **text**. See [ask] and [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on meta.

Comment: Please provide the output of `flutter doctor`